# What are the differences between vector, matrix and array data types?

Tags: arrays, r, types

R comes with three types to store lists of homogenous objects: `vector`, `matrix` and `array`.

As far as I can tell:

- `vector` is special cases for 1 dimension arrays
- `matrix` is a special case for 2 dimensions arrays
- `array` can also have any dimension level (including 1 and 2).

What is the difference between using 1D arrays over vectors and 2D arrays over matrices? Do we need to cast between those, or will it happen automagically?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no difference between a `matrix` and a 2D `array`:

```
> x <- matrix(1:10, 2)
> y <- array(1:10, c(2, 5))
> identical(x, y)
[1] TRUE
...
```

`matrix` is just a more convenient constructor, and there are many functions and methods that only accept 2D arrays (a.k.a. matrices).

Internally, arrays are just vectors with a dimension attribute:

```
...
> attributes(x)
$dim
[1] 2 5

> dim(x) <- NULL
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> z <- 1:10
> dim(z) <- c(2, 5)
> is.matrix(z)
[1] TRUE
```

To cite the [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html):

> Matrices and arrays are simply vectors with the attribute `dim` and
>   optionally `dimnames` attached to the vector.
>
> [...]
>
> The `dim` attribute is used to implement arrays. The content of the
>   array is stored in a vector in column-major order and the `dim`
>   attribute is a vector of integers specifying the respective extents of
>   the array. R ensures that the length of the vector is the product of
>   the lengths of the dimensions. The length of one or more dimensions
>   may be zero.
>
> A vector is not the same as a one-dimensional array since the latter
>   has a dim attribute of length one, whereas the former has no dim
>   attribute.

Comment: "...Internally arrays are just vectors...." - how about the fact that class function gives different results for vector and one dimension array?

Comment: What is your question? There are implicit classes in R.

Comment: @Roland Maybe you should edit your answer to include these details of "there are implicit classes". It may be useful to have an exhaustive explanation of how to use functions such as `class()`, `mode()` and `typeof()` to eventually determine the difference between vectors, arrays and matrices, etc.