# Why is class considered to be a special case of vector in R?

Tags: r

I am currently reading [Hands-on Programming with R](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028574.do). The author wrote the following paragraph -

> A class is a special case of an atomic vector. For example, the die
>   matrix is a special case of a double vector. Every element in the
>   matrix is still a double, but the elements have been arranged into a
>   new structure. R added a class attribute to die when you changed its
>   dimensions. This class describes die’s new format. Many R functions
>   will specifically look for an object’s class attribute, and then
>   handle the object in a predetermined way based on the attribute.

From what I have understood, shouldn't this statement be the other way around - vector is a special case of matrix because its dimensions are `Nx1` instead of `NxM`. Similarity, shouldn't vector be a special case of a class because vector has `NULL` class.

Why is it not the case?

Comment: "A class is a special case of an atomic vector." That's just nonsense (there are many classes that are not atomic vectors and atomic vectors don't have class attributes). I explain how R implements arrays there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33982741/1412059

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the pointer. Even the language specification supports the fact that the class is just a vector with dimname attribute. Could you please mention some class which are not atomic vectors?

Comment: No, a class is an R object with a class attribute (or one of the implicit classes, such as "matrix" or "numeric"). Examples are numerous, but, as one example, a data.frame is a list with class attribute "data.frame" (and "list" is an implicit class).

Comment: And "Many R functions will specifically look for an object’s class attribute"? I hope not. Just call the generic, and let the S3 OO mechanism handle dispatch. No need to look at a class attribute, and that breaks inheritance if you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the author refers to (in a bad way imho), is the internal representation of objects. They are all some type of "list" with extra bits of information that define how R deals with it.

Take for example a matrix. A matrix is a vector with an extra attribute called "dim". It is this attribute that makes it a matrix. Removing the attribute, shows the underlying vector structure:

```
> x <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 5)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

> attributes(x)
$dim
[1] 2 5

> attr(x,"dim") <- NULL
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Data frames on the other hand, are special cases of a list. They are defined as S3 classes, again by an attribute. This time the attribute is called "class".

The S3 system is a very rudimentary implementation of OOP: there is no formal class definition, so the class of an instance is only defined by the attributes. Generic functions like `print()`, `summary()` and so on look at that class attribute, and search for the specific method for that class.

Note how the attributes are a named list with extra information on the object. In the case of a data frame, that's the row and column names next to the class attribute itself:

```
> class(iris)
[1] "data.frame"
> attributes(iris)
$names
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
$row.names
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   ... 
$class
[1] "data.frame"
> class(iris) <- NULL
> class(iris)
[1] "list"
```

Other instances of S3 classes are also defined by that attribute "class". If you do a linear model for example, the output is a list with a class attribute that makes it of the class "lm". Removing the class attribute leaves you with a named list.

When talking about S4, things become a bit more complex. But again an S4 object is a list-like structure, where every slot is an "element" of that "list". Note that you can't remove an attribute or so to get to a normal list like you could do with an S3 class. S4 is more strictly defined, and hence the general idea voiced by the author does not apply to S4 objects.

To answer your question about vector and matrix: A vector does not have dimensions in R. Or more exact: it does not have a dimension attribute. You can add one, but then you end up with a one dimensional array. They do behave very similar to a vector, but not always. So a matrix is internally a vector with one small extra piece of information. I wouldn't call that "a special case of a vector", but it's true that a matrix is derived from a vector and not the other way around.