# What is the dimensionality of a vector?

Tags: r

I am a bit confused about the classification of data structures from [this section](https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/blob/master/Data-structures.Rmd) of Advanced R.

In particular, array have non-defined dimensionality, atomic vectors are 1d. How can you prove it using R? Is this classification supposed to reflect the output from `dim()`?

```
> dim(c(1))
NULL
> dim(array(1))
[1] 1
```

From this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982640/difference-between-vector-matrix-and-array-datatypes-besides-dimension-limitati) it sounds like `dim()` addresses dimensionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the return value of `dim` is not what you think it is.

From the documentation of `dim`: it returns

> **Value**
>
> For an array (and hence in particular, for a matrix) dim retrieves the dim attribute of the object. It is NULL or a vector of mode integer.

It doesn't return dimension of vector space (1-d, 2-d etc) of the object.

If an object doesn't have the `dim` attribute set, we can expect `NULL`.

```
atv <- c(1)
attributes(atv)
# NULL

 
ara <- array(1)
attributes(ara)
#$dim
#[1] 1
```

It seems to me what one way atomic vectors differ from other data types is not having `dim` attributes. As soon as you set `dim` to a atomic vector, it becomes a matrix or an array.

```
class(atv)
# "numeric"

dim(atv) <- 1
class(atv)
# "array"
dim(atv)
# 1
```

Comment: So the attribute `dim` has nothing to do with dimensionality?

Comment: @Dambo Internally, all R data objects are unidimensional vectors. Dimensions are just a layer of decoration on top of that, only defined when useful. So dim returns dimensionality measurements iff the inspected object has such a decoration/attribute.

Comment: @Frank so why does an array have no dimensionality (according to the link to the chapter)?

Comment: @Dambo In that table, `nd` stands for "n-dimensional" where n >= 1 if that's what you mean by "no dimensionality". Btw, if there's a longer discussion, it could go to the R chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public