# Concrete examples on why dimension is not defined for vectors (vectors are dimensionless) in R?

Tags: r, vector, dimension

[Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-December/147623.html): in R, to arise the need to define dimension for a vector,

M. JORGENSEN (Dept of Stat, U of Waikato, NZ):
"Would it not make sense to have `dim(A)=length(A)` for all vectors?"

B.D. RIPLEY (Dept of Applied Statistics, Oxford, UK):
"No.  A one-dimensional array and a vector are not the same thing.
There are subtle differences, such as what `names()` means (see `?names`).

That a 1D array and a vector *print* in the same way does occasionally 
lead to confusion, but then you also cannot tell from your printout that `A` 
has type `integer` and not `double`.
......
My question:
(1) Not only I cannot figure out the subtle difference on `names()` but also
(2) I cannot produce a concrete example about "telling from the printout that `A` 
has type `integer` and not `double` issue".

Any help to clarify JORGENSEN-RIPLEY discussion (with concrete examples in R) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the first question, let's first create a vector and a 1-d array:

```r
(vector <- 1:10)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

(arr_1d <- array(1:10, dim = 10))
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If we give the objects some names, we can see the difference
that Ripley alludes to by looking at the attributes:

```r
names(vector) <- letters[1:10]
names(arr_1d) <- letters[1:10]

attributes(vector)
#> $names
#>  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
attributes(arr_1d)
#> $dim
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> $dimnames
#> $dimnames[[1]]
#>  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

That is, the 1-d array doesn't actually have a `names` attribute,
but rather a `dimnames` attribute (which is a list, not a vector),
the first element of which `names()` actually accesses.

This is covered in the "Note" section in `?names`:

> For vectors, the names are one of the attributes with restrictions on
>   the possible values. For pairlists, the names are the tags and
>   converted to and from a character vector.
>
> For a one-dimensional array the names attribute really is
>   dimnames[[1]].

Here we also see the lack of a `dim`
attribute for vectors. ([A related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982640/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-matrix-and-array-data-types) covers the differences between arrays and vectors, too.)

The additional attributes and their storage method means that
1-d arrays always take up a little more memory than their vector equivalent:

```r
# devtools::install_github("r-lib/lobstr")
lobstr::obj_size(vector)
#> 848 B
lobstr::obj_size(arr_1d)
#> 1,056 B
```

However, that's about the only reason I can think of why one
would want to have separate types for vectors and 1-d arrays. I would assume this was really the question that Jorgensen was
asking, i.e. *why* have a separate `vector` type without the `dim`
attribute at all; and I don't think Ripley really addresses that.
I'd be very interested to hear other rationale for this.

As for point 2), when you create a vector with `:` it
is always an integer:

```r
vector <- 1:10
typeof(vector)
#> [1] "integer"
```

A double with the same values will print the same:

```r
double <- as.numeric(vector)
typeof(double)
#> [1] "double"

double
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But integers and doubles are not the same thing:

```r
identical(vector, double)
#> [1] FALSE
```

The differences between integers and doubles in R are subtle, the main
one being that integers take up less space in memory.

```r
lobstr::obj_size(vector)
#> 88 B
lobstr::obj_size(double)
#> 168 B
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660094/whats-the-difference-between-integer-class-and-numeric-class-in-r) for a more comprehensive overview of the differences between integers and doubles.

Created on 2018-07-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).