# Why does cbind give a different output to c when two numbers are used as inputs?

Tags: r, vector, concatenation

Consider the following outrageously simple example:

```
> c(42,50)
[1] 42 50
> cbind(42,50)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   42   50
```

Clearly, `c` and `cbind` are giving different outputs. But why is this? For a simple case like this, why aren't both of their approaches to concatenation the same? What's the technical difference between their outputs? I was expecting both to be numeric vectors of length two, but `cbind`'s output is clearly something else.

Comment: Because the documentation says so? "Value: For the default method, a matrix combining the ... arguments column-wise or row-wise."

Comment: You might be interested in this old answer of mine regarding the difference between a vector and a matrix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982640/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-matrix-and-array-data-types/33982741#33982741

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `?c`vs `?cbind` :

```
c                     package:base                     R Documentation

Combine Values into a Vector or List
```

vs

```
cbind                   package:base                   R Documentation   

Combine R Objects by Rows or Columns
```

they are, by definition, not the same.

In other words, I see no reason to expect the same output. That being said, here's how you could get the same structure just in case :

> ```
> > str(as.vector(cbind(42,50)))
>   num [1:2] 42 50
> ```

vs

> ```
> > str(c(42,50))  
>   num [1:2] 42 50
> ```