# Issue with creating a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

So I'm having an issue creating matrices in R.
My laptop had crashed and Rstudio has been reinstalled recently (just in case that's relevant).

I have used a pretty basic code, but the object that's created is a "matrix""array". Even though that is not what I told R to do.

This is what I did plus the result I'm getting.

```
> objectA <- matrix(nrow=135, ncol = 135, data = 0)
> class(objectA)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

How do I get a normal matrix object?
as.matrix is also converting the objects into "matrix""array"

Comment: This is not a bug. `?array` tells us that _An array in R can have one, two or more dimensions. It is simply a vector which is stored with additional attributes giving the dimensions (attribute "dim") and optionally names for those dimensions (attribute "dimnames"). A two-dimensional array is **the same thing as a matrix**._

Comment: You create `objectA` and then check for class of `objectB`? Nonetheless, that is a normal matrix object. What is the class `"matrix" "array"` stopping you from doing?

Comment: Relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33982640/680068

Comment: @Ronak Shah, Sorry, I had renamed the object before posting.. it here, clearly forgot to change all the lines.. but results are the same

Comment: @ekoam Yes, a matrix is a 2-d array, but what I need is an object of class "matrix". The problem arises downstream, when I run functions (that are expecting class "matrix") on the object. I end up getting errors.

Comment: Why do you need that? I cannot think of any situation that you ever need something like that. If you want to check whether an object is of a matrix class, then just do something like this `inherits(objectA, "matrix")`. @AnneHeloiseTheo

Comment: Please post the code which returns you an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a change in R 4.0.0 -- see the second entry for that version in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html:

- matrix objects now also inherit from class "array", so e.g., class(diag(1)) is c("matrix", "array"). This invalidates code incorrectly assuming that class(matrix_obj)) has length one.

  S3 methods for class "array" are now dispatched for matrix objects.

Previously it was bad form to check that the class was equal to a particular value, now it doesn't work.  You (or their authors) will need to fix the downstream tests.  The test that works in both old and new versions is

```
if (inherits(matrix_obj, "matrix")) ...
```